# On roblox studio how do you make a script only activate after choosing a dialog option?

Tags: roblox

I need this to be answered im struggling?

Answer (score 0):

On the dialog choice insert a script. 
 The script will look something like this:

```
local dialog = script.Parent
local activateScript = game.Workspace.["Name Of Your Script"] --Or whatever the path is

dialog.DialogChoiceSelected:connect(function(player, choice) --This is getting the service when the choice is selected
    if choice == script.Parent.DialogChoice.ChoiceA then --Choice A is what you named the option in studio
        --Do what you want to do
        activateScript.Disabled = false --Activated Script
    end
    elseif choice = script.Parent.DialogChoice.ChoiceB then
       --Do what you want
    end
    --Repeat for all choices
end)
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask and I will answer if I know.

There is also a wiki page on it [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Dialog_Shop_Tutorial)